# Can I dynamically create a column value based on another column value?

Tags: list

If I create a list in SharePoint, and lets say I have 1 column that has a value of someone's name

```
John Dough
```

When his name is added for the first time, for a specific column, is there anyway I can ask that same list to dynamically add a new sibling column value with his email address...

```
jdough@company.com
```

Can this be accomplished within the User Interface of SharePoint? Is this possible today?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by adding new calculated column, with the following formula:

```
=LOWER(LEFT([Title],1) & RIGHT([Title],LEN([Title])-INT(FIND(" ",[Title]))) & "@company.com")
```

Just replace `[Title]` with the name of your column.
This is the basic formula that covers situations when there is a space character in the name. If you need additional checks you can add some IF statements in the formula, to check for space character.